# How can I call functions via user input (with included parameters/values) using a similar method?

Tags: python, function

What I'm attempting to do is to take key words from user inputs and from there im attempting to call a function and parameter. For instance, if I were to remove a variable from a list, I would type remove -1 for the last value etc.

Code:

```
todo_list = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6]

def add_item(item):
    item = 0    
    while len(todo_list) < maxLengthList:
        item = input("Please enter your desired tasks: ")
        todo_list.append(task)
    print("Your to-do list so far: ")
    
def remove_item(idx):
    del todo_list[idx]
    return("This function removes! ")
    
def move_item(idx1, idx2):
    return("This function moves! ")
    
def list_items():
    for x in range(len(todo_list)):
        return todo_list[x]
    
cmd_map =  {'add': add_item, 'remove': remove_item, 'move': move_item, 'list': list_items}

while True:
    
    cmd = input("Please input command: ")
   
    if cmd.strip() == 'add':
        add_item(item)
    
    elif cmd.strip() == 'remove':
        remove_item(idx)
        exit()
   
    elif cmd.strip() == 'move':
        move_item(idx1 ,idx2)
        exit()
        
    elif cmd.strip() == 'list':
        list_items()
        exit()
    
    elif cmd.strip() in cmd_map.keys():
        cmd_map[cmd]()
        
    else:
        print("sorry no function for that!")
```

Comment: You need to split your input into tokens.

Comment: how do i tokenize my inputs as the to-do list theoretically can be endless too. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
while True:
    
    cmd = input("Please input command: ")
    vars = cmd.split(' ')
    if vars[0].strip() == 'add':
        add_item(int(vars[1].strip()))
    
    elif vars[0].strip() == 'remove':
        remove_item(int(vars[1].strip()))
        exit()
   
    elif vars[0].strip() == 'move':
        move_item(int(vars[1].strip()) ,int(vars[2].strip()))
        exit()
        
    elif vars[0].strip() == 'list':
        list_items()
        exit()
    
    elif vars[0].strip() in cmd_map.keys():
        cmd_map[cmd]()
        
    else:
        print("sorry no function for that!")
```

To eliminate any Extra spaces from user,
and to remove case sensitiveness
try:

```
import re
while True:
    flag = 0
    cmd = input("Please input command: ")
    vars = re.split(r'\s+', cmd.strip())
    if re.search('add', vars[0], flags=re.IGNORECASE):
        flag = 1
        add_item(int(vars[1]))
    
    elif re.search('remove', vars[0], flags=re.IGNORECASE):
        flag = 1
        remove_item(int(vars[1]))
        exit()
   
    elif re.search('move', vars[0], flags=re.IGNORECASE):
        flag = 1
        move_item(int(vars[1]) ,int(vars[2]))
        exit()
        
    elif re.search('list', vars[0], flags=re.IGNORECASE):
        flag = 1
        list_items()
        exit()
    
    else:
        for key in cmd_map.keys():
            if re.search(key, vars[0], flags=re.IGNORECASE):
                cmd_map[key]()
                flag = 1
                break
    if flag == 0:
        print("sorry no function for that!")
```

You can also use `exec()` to dynamically execute statements

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much for the help! though it returns valueError as an invalid literal with base 10, would that be just because it accepts integers only?

Comment: You can enter any kind of input you desire, I've casted the parameters to integer